# i need to compare 2 template and need to get string from defined variable in html with PHP

Tags: php, regex

Here in database i have stored template like below, in that i have defined its variable like [string:cover_ratio] and "[image:large_image] and so on

```
<div class="cbp-item logos cbp-ratio-even" data-cbp-coverratio="[string:cover_ratio]"><div class="cbp-caption" style=""><div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAP///////yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="" width="1900" height="1267" data-cbp-src="[image:large_image]"></div><div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap"><div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter"><div class="cbp-l-caption-body"><a href="[image:thumbnail_image]" class="cbp-lightbox cbp-l-caption-buttonLeft" data-title="View Larger">View Larger</a></div></div></div></div><div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-title">[string:dish_name]</div><div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-desc">[string:dish_description]</div></div>
```

And i have same template with its value like below HTML

```
<div class="cbp-item logos cbp-ratio-even" data-cbp-coverratio="4:3"><div class="cbp-caption" style=""><div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAP///////yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="" width="1900" height="1267" data-cbp-src="https://kyousushi.ca/gallery/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Salmon-Sashimi.jpg"></div><div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap"><div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter"><div class="cbp-l-caption-body"><a href="https://kyousushi.ca/gallery/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Salmon-Sashimi.jpg" class="cbp-lightbox cbp-l-caption-buttonLeft" data-title="View Larger">View Larger</a></div></div></div></div><div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-title">Salmon Sashimi</div><div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-desc">Salmon Sashimi</div></div>
```

You can see in this template for variable [string:cover_ratio] have value 4:3, i need to get all that defined value, in this template can anyone please help me for that ?

Comment: but it is in remote db, i didn't stored it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer:

I tested this and it works - basically remove the static parts of the string and save the rest:

```
//template string
$template = '<div class="cbp-item logos cbp-ratio-even" data-cbp-coverratio="[string:cover_ratio]"><div class="cbp-caption" style=""><div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAP///////yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="" width="1900" height="1267" data-cbp-src="[image:large_image]"></div><div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap"><div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter"><div class="cbp-l-caption-body"><a href="[image:thumbnail_image]" class="cbp-lightbox cbp-l-caption-buttonLeft" data-title="View Larger">View Larger</a></div></div></div></div><div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-title">[string:dish_name]</div><div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-desc">[string:dish_description]</div></div>';

//string with values inserted
$edited = '<div class="cbp-item logos cbp-ratio-even" data-cbp-coverratio="4:3"><div class="cbp-caption" style=""><div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAP///////yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="" width="1900" height="1267" data-cbp-src="https://kyousushi.ca/gallery/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Salmon-Sashimi.jpg"></div><div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap"><div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter"><div class="cbp-l-caption-body"><a href="https://kyousushi.ca/gallery/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Salmon-Sashimi.jpg" class="cbp-lightbox cbp-l-caption-buttonLeft" data-title="View Larger">View Larger</a></div></div></div></div><div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-title">Salmon Sashimi</div><div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-desc">Salmon Sashimi</div></div>';

//this is where we will store the values
$gottenValues = [];

//get the variable names
preg_match_all('/\[.*\]/U', $template, $names);
$names = $names[0];

//get the static parts of the string
$templateParts = preg_split('/\[.*\]/U', $template);

//replace the static parts of the edited string, and the remaining parts are the values
foreach($templateParts as $index=>$part){

    if($index===0){
        //for the first part, just replace the static part of the string
        $edited = substr($edited, strlen($part));
        continue;
    }

    //split the editied string by the next static part, and use the first art as the value
    $edited = explode($part, $edited);

    //save the value based on the variable name
    $gottenValues[trim($names[$index - 1], '[]')] = $edited[0];

    //update the editied string
    $edited = $edited[1];
}

//print the resulting object
echo '<pre>';
print_r($gottenValues);
```

this code will return the result:

```
Array
(
    [string:cover_ratio] => 4:3
    [image:large_image] => https://kyousushi.ca/gallery/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Salmon-Sashimi.jpg
    [image:thumbnail_image] => https://kyousushi.ca/gallery/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Salmon-Sashimi.jpg
    [string:dish_name] => Salmon Sashimi
    [string:dish_description] => Salmon Sashimi
)
```

Comment: 4:3 and Salmon Sashimi this are dynamic values, that i need to get from string

Comment: If you will add space in html tags then it doesn't working correctly can you help for that ?

Comment: My answer only works if the strings match other than the variables, can you provide an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: You could start by replacing all the whitespace characters in the strings, then it should still work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190704/discussion-between-nikul-panchal-and-maxpelic).

Comment: i need your help, code is not working for this string, can you please help me for that ?  here is my stackoverflow link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55605301/string-compare-diffrence-not-working-properly-in-php?noredirect=1#comment97908473_55605301