# string compare diffrence not working properly in php

Tags: php

I have 2 strings, I need to compare difference 2 strings and get the values of that, I did code but it is working for 2 variables only, here i have put my whole code, can anyone please give me solution for that, I need value by variable defined in the string, in `$template` string there is defined variable

```
[string:class_cover_ratio]
```

And value of that string need to match in `$edited` string, so it value will be

```
class="cbp-item logos cbp-ratio-even" data-cbp-coverratio="4:3"
```

So on for the other variable compare the string and get value for that, here is my code

```
$template = '<div[string:class_cover_ratio]><div[string:class_2]><div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAP///////yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="" data-cbp-src="[image:thumbnail_name]" width="[string:large_width]" height="[string:large_height]"></div><div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap"><div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter"><div class="cbp-l-caption-body"><a href="[image:large_name]" class="cbp-lightbox cbp-l-caption-buttonLeft" data-title="[string:title]">[string:view_larger_text]</a></div></div></div></div><div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-title">[string:dish_name]</div><div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-desc">[string:dish_description]</div></div>';
$edited = '<div class="cbp-item logos cbp-ratio-even" data-cbp-coverratio="4:3"><div class="cbp-caption" style=""><div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAP///////yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="" data-cbp-src="http://cubewp.axcelmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Ankimo-thum.jpg" width="400" height="300"></div><div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap"><div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter"><div class="cbp-l-caption-body"><a href="http://cubewp.axcelmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Ankimo.jpg" class="cbp-lightbox cbp-l-caption-buttonLeft" data-title="Monkfish Liver, lightly garnished">View Larger</a></div></div></div></div><div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-title">Ankimo</div><div class="cbp-l-grid-projects-desc">Monkfish Liver, lightly garnished</div></div>';

function test($edited, $template) {
    $gottenValues = [];
    preg_match_all('/\[.*\]/U', $template, $names);
    $names = $names[0];
    $templateParts = preg_split('/\[.*\]/U', $template);
    foreach ($templateParts as $index => $part) {
        if ($index === 0) {
            $part = trim($part);
            $edited = trim($edited);
            $edited = substr($edited, strlen($part));
            continue;
        }
        $edited = explode($part, $edited);
        $gottenValues[trim($names[$index - 1], '[]')] = $edited[0];
        if (isset($edited[1])) {
            $edited = $edited[1];
        } else {
            $edited = "";
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($gottenValues);
    die;
}

test($edited, $template);
```

And i am getting below output

```
Array
(
    [string:class_cover_ratio] =>  class="cbp-item logos cbp-ratio-even" data-cbp-coverratio="4:3"
    [string:class_2] =>  class="cbp-caption" style=""
    [image:thumbnail_name] => 
    [string:large_width] => 
    [string:large_height] => 
    [image:large_name] => 
    [string:title] => 
    [string:view_larger_text] => 
    [string:dish_name] => 
    [string:dish_description] => 
)
```

In output you can see i am getting only 2 variable value, other values are not working for me, can anyone please help me for that ?

Comment: What's the point of the `if ($index === 0)` block? All those variables will be overwritten on the next iteration.

Comment: Yes we do not need to consider first index

Comment: I understand that you're skipping the first index, but why do you set the variables `$part` and `$edited` when you're skipping it?

Comment: Also, what's the purpose of the `if (isset($edited[1]))` block? You reassign `$edited`, but never use the new value.

Comment: Never mind, I see that you use `$edited` from the previous iteration as the argument when doing `$edited = explode($part, $edited);`.

Comment: This code is too confusing for me. I suggest you insert a bunch of print statements to see what all the variables contain on each iteration.

Comment: I am doing debugging of it, but not getting any solution

Comment: @Bramar do you other solution for it ?

Comment: I don't understand how it's supposed to work. Can you edit the question and explain the algorithm?

Comment: I need to compare 2 string $template and $edited string and get value of the variable like [string:class_cover_ratio] value will be class="cbp-item logos cbp-ratio-even" data-cbp-coverratio="4:3", same this will be happen for other variable

Comment: Looks like my code will not work, we need to find another way from scratch

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, I don't understand HOW you're doing it. If you can't explain clearly to a human, you'll never be able to explain it to a computer.

Comment: try adding another backslash on you regex: `'/\\[.*\\]/U'`